# Nginx config - Why Yii2 application is not served after I added "location = /"?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have Nginx configured and running for some time now. It is handling 3 applications.
Most important is the application #1. It consists of 3 modules: account, participant and admin. Therefore these addresses allow logging into the application for different types of users:
`domain.com/account/login`, `domain.com/participant/login` or `domain.com/admin/login`
Also the homepage `domain.com` is handled by the same application.
Nginx config was very simple to serve this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
root $rootPath;
index index.html index.php;
# PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

Thanks to this Home page and Modules were handled by Yii2.

I don't think it should be relevant but there are 2 more apps configured in nginx under locations `/application2` and `/ application3`. One is php Zend app and the other - php and javascript app.

Now I need to replace homepage with Wordpress one-pager. Desired solution is to have:

- homepage served by Wordpress at `domain.com`
- Yii2 application modules working as before, so that all `/participant`, `/account` and `/admin` locations are served by `index.php` at `$rootPath`
- 2 other applications working as before at `domain.com/application2` and `domain.com/application3`.

For handling Wordpress page I have added one section `location = /` to redirect main address to Wordpress app. But I cannot add nested location for PHP because I am getting this error: `location "/(.+.php$)" cannot be inside the exact location "/"`

So I changed the approach. I have set global root to Wordpress path: `root $wpPath;` and added locations for account, participant and admin modules:

```
location /account {
    root $rootPath;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # process PHP here
    location ~ /account/(.+\.php$) {
        alias $rootPath/$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The main page (Wordpress) works perfectly fine. But the Yii2 application modules (like /aaccount) return 404 - Not found. What is wrong with above setup?

Comment: Have you deleted some configuration? I cannot see how your Yii2 application worked before.

Comment: I omitted another config file that I thought only contained server part with "listen", ssl and variable settings. Now I checked it also contains one location part: `location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }`
Does it explain why Yii2 app works?

Comment: OK, I will rewrite my question because I have confused myself with the changes. :)